# Can somebody help on how to return each array in function and then calling it all at main function? [c]

Tags: c

So here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double CalculateFinalScore(int assignment[], int midterm[], int finalExam[], double *scoreSum[]) {

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        *scoreSum[i] = (assignment[i] * 0.2) + (midterm[i] * 0.3) + (finalExam[i] * 0.5);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    const int NUM_SCORES = 4; // Array size
    double testScores[NUM_SCORES]; // User test scores
    int i = 0;
    double finalScore = 0.0;
    int x[100];
    int y[100];
    int z[100];
    double q;

    // Prompt user to enter test scores
    printf("Enter %d students test scores:\n", NUM_SCORES);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; ++i) {
        printf("Input student %d assignment score: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &(x[i]));
        printf("Input student %d midterm score: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &(y[i]));
        printf("Input student %d final exam score: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &(z[i]));
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    // Call function to calculate final score
    CalculateFinalScore(x, y, z, &q);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; ++i) {
        printf("Final student test score: ");
        printf("%lf\n", q);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I want to have an output that display the final score for each student that I have inputed before. But the when my code tries to display the output its always segmentation fault. I tried to return the array before but it seems that it doesn't fix it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `double q;` ---> `double q[NUM_SCORES]` and double `*scoreSum[]` --> `double scoreSum[]`

Comment: The argument `double *scoreSum[]` is equal to `double **scoreSum`. You call the function passing `&q` where `q` is a single `double` value, meaning that `&q` is of type `double *`. Perhaps `q` should be an array just like `x`, `y` and `z` (i.e. `double q[100]`), and then passed and used just like them?

Comment: Get rid of the `*` next to `scoreSum` to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code (not tested)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUM_SCORES 4

double CalculateFinalScore(int assignment[], int midterm[], int finalExam[], double scoreSum[], uint8_t num_scores) 
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num_scores; ++i) 
    {
        scoreSum[i] = (assignment[i] * 0.2) + (midterm[i] * 0.3) + (finalExam[i] * 0.5);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    double testScores[NUM_SCORES]; // User test scores
    int i = 0;
    int x[NUM_SCORES];
    int y[NUM_SCORES];
    int z[NUM_SCORES];

    // Prompt user to enter test scores

    printf("Enter %d students test scores:\n", NUM_SCORES);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; ++i) 
    {
        printf("Input student %d assignment score: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &(x[i]));
        printf("Input student %d midterm score: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &(y[i]));
        printf("Input student %d final exam score: ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &(z[i]));
        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("\n");
    // Call function to calculate final score
    CalculateFinalScore(x, y, z, testScores, NUM_SCORES);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; ++i) 
    {
        printf("Final student %d test score: ", )i+1));
        printf("%lf\n", testScores[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. You are passing a single double while your function need an array
2. Your function needs an array of `double`, not a pointer to an array of `double`